# SQL for Grouping Teams by Rank

Tags: sql, aggregate, non-equi-join

Given two tables named team and award, I need to assign teams to an award based on each team's rank. Here are the two tables:

team

| team_id | name | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | stars | 4 |
| 2 | worms | 2 |
| 3 | birds | 1 |
| 4 | dogs | 3 |
| 5 | clouds | 5 |
| 6 | broncos | 8 |
| 7 | cars | 11 |
| 8 | llamas | 7 |
| 9 | cats | 9 |
| 10 | locusts | 6 |
| 11 | bulls | 10 |

award

| threshold | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000.00 |
| 2 | 7000.00 |
| 3 | 5000.00 |
| 6 | 2000.00 |
| 10 | 500.00 |

The teams must be assigned to awards like this:

| rank | threshold | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10000.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 7000.00 |
| 3 | 3 | 5000.00 |
| 4 | 6 | 2000.00 |
| 5 | 6 | 2000.00 |
| 6 | 6 | 2000.00 |
| 7 | 10 | 500.00 |
| 8 | 10 | 500.00 |
| 9 | 10 | 500.00 |
| 10 | 10 | 500.00 |
| 11 | null | null |

I've never used a non-equi join before but thought this might be a classic example where a non-equi join would be helpful. I wrote this MySQL query which gives the results that I want:

```
SELECT t.name, t.rank, MIN(a.threshold) AS threshold, MAX(a.amount) AS amount
FROM team AS t
    INNER JOIN award AS a ON t.rank <= a.threshold
GROUP BY t.team_id
ORDER BY t.rank;
```

| name | rank | threshold | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| birds | 1 | 1 | 10000.00 |
| worms | 2 | 2 | 7000.00 |
| dogs | 3 | 3 | 5000.00 |
| stars | 4 | 6 | 2000.00 |
| clouds | 5 | 6 | 2000.00 |
| locusts | 6 | 6 | 2000.00 |
| llamas | 7 | 10 | 500.00 |
| broncos | 8 | 10 | 500.00 |
| cats | 9 | 10 | 500.00 |
| bulls | 10 | 10 | 500.00 |

My question is, "Are there problems with using a non-equi join that I don't understand?" Or in other words, "Is there a more standard SQL approach to this problem?"

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: I'm using MySQL but am also interested in answers for other database systems.

Answer (score 1):

Also standard, but not a feature in every RDBMS, is a [LATERAL JOIN](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-lateral-join/).

```
SELECT t.team_id, t.name, t.rank
, award.threshold
, award.amount
FROM team t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    select
      min(a.threshold) as threshold
    , max(a.amount) as amount
    from award a
    where a.threshold >= t.rank
) award
ORDER BY t.rank;
```

It's similar to a correlated sub-query.
But you can get more columns from it.